# Jquery scrollto with offset

Tags: jquery

I have this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pcmdo

However, at the moment when it does the `scrollto` using the text links in the black menu it scrolls so that the black bar is inside the section. I want to have it so the black bar is on top of the section. just enough to trigger that section as active.

Can anyone show me how to do that. I think it would be something like this (but this is more like sudo code):

```
scrollTop: $('#'+sectionId).offset().top-nav.height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a pixel to have the section active:

```
scrollTop: ($('#'+sectionId).offset().top - $('nav').height()) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`nav.height` should be `$(nav).height()`